# Backup software for incremental swapped-out drives?

Tags: windows, backup, acronis-trueimage, incremental-backup

We're using Acronis Home 11 to backup our main Windows machine at the office. We have a set of portable hard drives that we swap out each week, for redundancy. We have incremental sets ( a new diff of the entire series each night) building on each drive.

However, from time to time, Acronis gets confused and sometimes makes a new full backup. This eats up a lot of drive on the disks. Also, I have to trick the Acronis script each time I swap out a drive and point it to the new incremental backup set. Finally, if a drive gets full, there's no way to partition the backup set on a drive. I found this out the hard way, and now one drive is full with one backup set. So now on the other drive, I have three folders of backup sets. When one starts to get full, I delete the oldest one and start a new set. That way one single drive never gets filled up with one single backup set.

I'm looking for a backup software that can backup Windows in incremental sets, and doesn't get tripped up with swapped out drives. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you assign the same drive letter for the two different drives?

Comment: Yeah, they show up with the same drive letter. I never have them plugged in at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up two separate scripts to do the different backups. When one drive is in, I enable its script and disable the other. It seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Acronis business package it has a lot more options and may solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

[crashplan](http://crashplan.com) likely would do the trick as well.